# What would the beracha be on tree-leaves?

Tags: halacha, food, blessing, trees

- What [blessing](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/Brachot.html) would one make on leaves from [woody] trees that are routinely eaten? Is it ha'eitz, because they came from a tree? Is it ha-adama, because they're not "fruit" but are vegetative? Is it shehakol, for some other reason?
- Are there any examples of leaves from [woody] trees that are routinely eaten? If so, do any halachic sources discuss what to make on them?

Comment: **This post won [weekly topic challenge](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/441) 5772-17 (week of Yisro 5772)! Congratulations!**

Answer (score 9):

The [Shulchan Aruch OC 202:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=208) discusses the bracha on a [caper bush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caper)<sup>[1]</sup>. The caper has multiple edible parts including leaves and berries. The Shulchan Aruch says the berries get a HaEtz because they are the main fruit ("Ikkar HaPeri") and the leaves get a HaAdamah. The Shaar HaTziyun sk 41 says the reason the leaves still get a HaAdamah is because the capers were planted for their leaves as well. He says that when people do not plant the capers for the leaves at all but solely for the fruit than the leaves revert to SheHaKol.

So in short, if the leaves are the main fruit of the tree they get a HaEtz. If they are not the main fruit but still an intended benfit of planting the tree, they get a HaAdamah. If they are completely unintended, they get a SheHaKol.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Capers are a common plant in parts of Israel and were often cultivated for their fruits. One famous caper-farmer is the Tanna [Elazar HaKappar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_ha-kappar). (see:[here](http://www.tapuz.co.il/blog/net/print.aspx?EntryId=1968965))

Answer (score -2):

According to the shulchan aruch harav capers are hoadomo too, being that they are planted for their leaves too.

Comment: What does this add to my answer?

Comment: @DoubleAA ... well, I guess it's an additional citation: not only does _SA_ hold that way, but _SAH_ does, too! And not only does _MB_ give that reason, _SAH_ does, too! Seems not a very useful answer: −1.

Comment: @Ew92 welcome to MiYodeya. Maybe you didn't see it but that question already had an answer. In that case the practice is to only post a new answer if it adds a different perspective or additional sources to the existing question(s). Alternatively if you want to comment on the existing answer, you can do so. Hope you will stick around, seems there is much knowledge you can contribute